# Go through undetermined number of Promises sequentially

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, bluebird, q

I have this class that has method `next` returning a `Promise`.

```js
class PromiseGenerator {
    constructor() {
        this.limit = 100;
        this.counter = 0;
    }
    next() {
        this.counter++;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(this.counter <= this.limit ? this.counter : false);
            }, 500);
        });
    }
}
```

Though example shows `100` it could return unlimited number of promises.

I need to execute all the promises in sequential order.

How can I achieve it?

Only solution I came up so far is recursive:

```js
const source = new PromiseGenerator();

(function loop() {
    source.next().then(counter => {
        if (counter) {
            console.log(counter);
            loop();
        } else {
            console.log('Done');
        }
    });
})();
```

As I understand `Node` at the moment [does not optimize tail calls](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) and it may lead to stack growth.

Is there a better way of doing this?

if some Promise library has it it will work but it would be nice to understand how to achieve it without library as well.

**Update 1:** Sorry I didn't make it clear right away: I am not in control of `PromiseGenerator` class, it is something I can use but cannot change. So the question is how to handle this situation.

**Update 2:** I went with @eikooc solution: Without `generators` but just with `async/await`. See example below.

Thanks!

Comment: Use generators instead. You can iterate the promises until you pass in a done signal

Comment: Did you want an answer that **doesn't** change your `PromiseGenerator` class?

Comment: @JaromandaX, good point. You are right, I cannot change it, it is preexisting code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A) are a perfect match for this. Construct a generator with the `function*` keyword:

```
function* promiseGenerator() {
  while(!someCondition) {
    yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})
  }
}
```

And then call it with:

```
const source = promiseGenerator()
source.next()
```

This will continue to give you new values. The return looks like this `{value: Promise, done: false}` until it is finished.
When the generator finishes the `done` value will change to `true`

If you want to keep using the class and just want a loop. You can also combine your class with a [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function loop() {
  const source = new PromiseGenerator()
  while (true) {
    const result = await source.next()
    if (result) {
      console.log(result)
    } else {
      console.log('done')
      break
    }
  }
}

loop()
```

Comment: This is just a condition to check. It is not defined here, but could be for example a counter that should be less than some value

Comment: When the generator no longer `yields` new values. It will return an object with a property `done: true`

Comment: Just wanted to clarify ... because you say *When the generator finishes the `done` value will change to true* - just clearing up it's not the same `done` :p - because your code, as is, is not executable

Comment: Ah okay. I'll edit the answer to better reflect this. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: while your answer is ok, how does it work with the class in the OP's question? The way I understand it, the OP doesn't want to change the class, he wants to know how use the promises it generates :p

Comment: I made a more specific example that answers OP's question better now :-)

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear right away: I am not in control of `PromiseGenerator` class, it is something I can use but cannot change.

Comment: @SmxCde the new example with the async loop uses just your class. I will keep the other examples above as they can serve use to someone else stumbling upon this thread

Comment: That's a good one, I +1'ed your answer, but it appeared async/await is not available to me :(

Comment: @SmxCde In that case you have multiple ways to go. Either code it in an environment where you have access to async/await and transpile with https://babeljs.io/ or find an implementation of async functions in es5 or something like that

Comment: @eikooc, You know what, I was wrong, I can use async/await and your solution works for me, thanks!